# insertar en tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tengo esta tabla que se genera dinámicamente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
desde el codigo:

```
$dis = $db->query("SELECT idciclista, ciclistaid, nombre, SUM(distancia) as distancia FROM ciclista,actividad,etapa  where ciclista.idciclista=actividad.ciclistaid and etapa.idetapa=actividad.etapa and etapa.idetapa = '$id' GROUP BY ciclistaid ORDER BY distancia DESC LIMIT 0,10");
$rdis = $dis->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>
```

---

```
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <form name="sumarpuntos" method="POST" action="prueba.php">
          <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Distancia</th>
                <th>Puntos</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <br>
            <?php
            foreach ($rdis as $key => $value) {
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $key+1 ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->nombre ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->distancia;?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pntdis[]" size="5"></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="pntid[]" value="<?php echo $value->ciclistaid;?>" size="5">
              </tr>
            <?php } ?>
         </table>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Asignar Puntos">
  
</form>
```

lo que necesito hacer es que los datos de "puntos" se carguen en la tabla siguiente, asociado a cada "ciclista" no logro hacerlo, como se haria, array? while? foreach??

la tabla donde tienen que ir los datos es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muchas gracias

Comment: faltaria saber los datos como vienen dados y que formato

Comment: Saludos. El `idciclista`que mencionas no lo ubico donde está; así mismo, la forma actual como los asocias (que -asumo- te falla) te falto colocarla para ver lo que quieres realizar y con ello hacerte sugerencia(s).

Comment: los datos los tengo con este:
$dis = $db->query("SELECT idciclista, ciclistaid, nombre, SUM(distancia) as distancia FROM ciclista,actividad,etapa  where ciclista.idciclista=actividad.ciclistaid and etapa.idetapa=actividad.etapa and etapa.idetapa = '$id' GROUP BY ciclistaid ORDER BY distancia DESC LIMIT 0,10");
$rdis = $dis->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: Hola, Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor edita tu pregunta usando el enlace Editar que está justo debajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas. Añade la info que pones en comentarios y todo lo que hace falta para saber cómo estás intentando insertar los nuevos datos asociados con la tabla. Así mismo, podrías indicar los tipos de dato de las columnas en la tabla para que la inserción funcione correctamente. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).